# DocuSign API question - template utilization

Tags: docusignapi, api-design

We are trying to set up a DocuSign API where we utilize information put in by the user on a website and then send that to our DocuSign account to have a template applied to it. When we are trying to create this scenario do we still need to have the API "tabs" section in the payload that is being sent to DocuSign? Our documents being sent will already have the anchor tags placed into them by another program (Smart Communications).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Smart Communications. When you send the envelope request (either via a template or directly) you need to specify where the tabs are located.

That tab information can come from any resource (perhaps Smart Communications). If you can elaborate more on your scenario (in terms of how Smart Com works etc.) I can give you a more specific answer. Thank you.